# Best NFC SDK for ACR122U and ACR1222L

Tags: android, sdk, nfc

I bought both readers without the SDK CD-ROM by mistake and now I cannot find any other options to develop NFC P2P applications. The vendor doesn't offer the SDK separately nor read my e-mails begging for a separate purchase of the SDK and do not offer it for download on their website.

Already tried gototags SDK and it doesn't support android protocols yet. Also, I've tried to contact TinyNFC team and they didn't answer my e-mails aswell...

I think I'm out of options. Do any of you have an alternative to the ACS SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There was an SDK on disk going with ACR122U Kit. 
Check it out [here](https://yadi.sk/d/qlTYH_8x6YHJ8A)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which is best. But I found SDK for ACR122U at this site

http://acr122u-nfc-reader-sdk.software.informer.com/download/

Comment: Missing package file for installation